# Rigify armature shaking when parented to object

Tags: animation, rigging, transforms, parent, rigify

I have a human character mesh with a rigify armature deform that works great. I have the character driving a car for the video but I cannot make the parenting look smooth. The rigged human sits in the car and follows, but there are micro corrections happening at a frame by frame level. I have tried using a secondary following object (Sphere parented to car, then armature parented to the sphere, same results. I have tried baking the animation as well to no success. This whole file is scaled down to be quite small which may be the issue. I already have the entire video animated and did not notice until exporting at a higher resolution, but it becomes very obvious in close up frames. There are tires and mirrors parented to the car, and they do not have the same issue, only certain items will not follow smoothly.

Comment: Odds are that you've got some kind of dependency loop in your armature, either parenting, constrains, or both; but it's impossible to tell from just a description.  Can you add your blend file to your question? ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.